# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Ant build failed: Could not load definitions

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty

I've upgraded my worklight server from v6.0 to v6.1.
The target environment is Liberty and Oracle database.
I've build a war for v6.1 and try to deploy it.
it fails with following error message:

```
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties. It could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of ANT jars have changed. So i had to take the new want named "worklight-ant-deployer.jar" instead of "worklight-ant.jar" in my xml config file.

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
  <classpath>
    <fileset dir="${worklight.server.install.dir}/WorklightServer">
      <include name="worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>
    </fileset>
 </classpath>
</taskdef>
```